# Getting the previous occurrence and next occurrence in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi I am working on oracle DB. The DB has one column date. It consists of the dates of 5 years with the dates model will be refreshed. Ex

```
DATE_TABLE

DATE 
------------
1-jan-2013
15-jan-2013
31-jan-2013
6-feb-2013
etc.........
```

now for today's date suppose `13th jan 2013`. The next refresh date will be `15th jan`. and previous refresh date is `1st jan`. to retrieve these two dates. Can i have any way without using PL/SQL. using regular select queries?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply use the below query, plain and simple. No need of pl/sql

```
SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM DATE_TABLE WHERE DATE > SYSDATE ;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two functions [LAG()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm#i1327527) (allows you to reference previous record) and [LEAD()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions079.htm#i83834) allows you to reference next record. Here is an example:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select '1-jan-2013'  from dual union all
  3    select '15-jan-2013' from dual union all
  4    select '31-jan-2013' from dual union all
  5    select '6-feb-2013'  from dual
  6  )
  7  select col                            as current_value
  8       , lag(col, 1) over(order by col) as prev_value
  9       , lead(col, 1) over(order by col)as next_value
 10    from t1
 11  ;
```

Result:

```
CURRENT_VALUE   PREV_VALUE    NEXT_VALUE
-------------   -----------   -----------
1-jan-2013      NULL          15-jan-2013
15-jan-2013     1-jan-2013    31-jan-2013
31-jan-2013     15-jan-2013   6-feb-2013
6-feb-2013      31-jan-2013   NULL
```

Comment: lead() and lag() functions introduced before 11g, http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/dbms/Analytic%20Functions%20in%20Oracle%208i%20and%209i.htm